# I got an error when export dataGridView data to excel

Tags: c#, excel

Here is my code:

```
public virtual void CopyToClipboard()
{
    gridView1.SelectAll();
    DataObject dataObj = gridView1.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);            
}

private void barButtonItem1_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    CopyToClipboard();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
    xlexcel.Visible = true;
    xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
    CR.Select();
    xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
}
```

And this is the error:

> Error 2   'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'GetClipboardContent' and no extension method 'GetClipboardContent' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All I need is export data form gridview to an excel file, only export what I see in the grid.

Comment: Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? Sometimes that's the issue for me.

Comment: I don't know. I'm a newbie of this language and after I changed "GetClipboardContent" to "CopyToClipboard" it said " Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataObject'"

Answer (score 0):

[GetClipboardContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getclipboardcontent(v=vs.110).aspx) is a [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getclipboardcontent(v=vs.110).aspx) method and you are using a `DevExpress.XtraGrid`. You can use [CopyToClipboard](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.CopyToClipboard.method).

Comment: I'm a newbie of this language and after I changed "GetClipboardContent" to "CopyToClipboard" it said " Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataObject'"